# How can I use tensorflow-gpu version if I have AMD graphics card?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, anaconda, object-detection

I'm using Anaconda in Windows 10 and I cannot install the current version of `tensorflow-gpu`. I have 4 GB AMD Radeon graphics card. So how can I run `Tensorflow-gpu` version in my laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run TensorFlow on AMD/ATI GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729853/how-to-run-tensorflow-on-amd-ati-gpu)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you need Linux and ROCm to have AMD GPUs supporting Tensorflow.
In my case with ubuntu and ROCm 1.9.1, in Python3:

```
import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)
>>1.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensflow works not just on CPUs it works on CPUs as well, so it will work on all systems provided that the dependencies are met. However, I thinkn your question is about having your GPU do the calculations with Tensorflow, which would be tensorflowGPU version. There are couple of things you can do.

1. Use Linux and ROCm as alternative. - ROCm was released a couple of years back to make exactly what you want possible. It can be a bit of a hassle and there will be about a 5-10% performance drop, but it will still be so much better than any CPU implementation of tensorflow.

[You can visit this link for installation and set up details for ROCm](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Installation_Guide/Installation-Guide.html)

2. Use TensorflowJS: If you are not very particular about using python then you can use Tensorflow.js works on all machines that supports opengl. I have not used it but I have read a bit about it. Please go through the docs